# sbt - deep child modules

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm new to sbt and I want to reproduce a complex project structure with many nested modules.

For example, I have the following structure:

```
.
build.sbt
|_web
  |_api
  |_dto
|_domain
```

build.sbt is as follows:

```
name := "myProject"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.6.10"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.example",
  version := "0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
)

// root module
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(domain, web)
// domain module
lazy val domain = project.settings(commonSettings)
// web module
lazy val web = project.settings(
  commonSettings,
  libraryDependencies := Seq("com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.6.10"),
  name := "myproj-web"
).dependsOn(domain)

// web api module
lazy val webApi = (project in file("./web/api")).settings(
  commonSettings,
  libraryDependencies := Seq("com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.6.10"),
  name := "myproj-web-api"
).dependsOn(domain)
```

First problem I have is I can't access my libraries in `web/api`, though I can in `web/`.
Second problem is that I don't like `file("./web/api")`. Is it possible to make sbt understand nested folders as it understands plain folders (like `web` or `domain`).
Also, is it possible then to have `build.sbt` for each module. For example, for `web` to contain build file for api and dto, but preserving aggregations and ability to call build only on root project and have all the rest projects be built.

Comment: What do you mean by "First problem I have is I can't access my libraries in web/api"?

Comment: I mean that "play" dependency is not available. I can't import anything of it.

Comment: same problem here ...